# How to get multiple view by Tag in onclick method

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello friends i want to get more than one view by its tag name which i have set by               programmatically , i want to visible one view when i click on another view the onclick method is common

My code is

```
public void onClick(final View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.gc();
    String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    Log.i("The Tag is here", "control is here" + v.getTag());
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewWithTag(v.getTag());
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 90, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    ll.startAnimation(animation);
    View v1 = (ImageButton) v;

    ImageButton iv = (ImageButton) v1.findViewWithTag("0delete");
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // Log.i("this is the", "======="+iv);

}
```

in this code i have set same tag name for both imagebutton or linear layout and i want to get imagebutton on linear layout click .

please tell me how i can achieve this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your code you have not use setTag() at all

Comment: i have used set tag in one method please tag is well sated this is further code

Comment: why do you need the same tag for two or more Views? just use different tags or write your own method that finds multiple Views with the given tag